# Ubuntu Server 22.04.3, installed gnome, no display

Tags: gnome, ssh, video, vga

Had Ubuntu 22.04.3 Server installed on an older tower with VGA, DVI integrated video hardware. Had brilliant idea to install Gnome GUI system for easier access while trying to set up samba for home based server.

Bad decision. Now I have no display to see what is happening. Flying blind.

Is there a way to gain access to system using SSH or what ever so I can install an PCI 2xHDMI card so I can see what is going on ?  I did not setup SSH when I setup ubuntu.

My thinking is that Gnome is way past the days of VGA and will not run the VGA display.

Display will not even show boot process or bios access screens.

Thanks for any help or insight beyond "it's bricked". I've already figured the Bricked or boat anchor thing figured!! Haa Haa.

Stan